# Bulk indexing is not working for me - mongoosastic

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

Only 1 batch is being indexed irrespective of the size of the batch or delay size.

```
teamSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
esClient: esClient,
bulk:{
batch: 10
}
});
```

Indexes only 10 even though there are more than 10 records in mongodb.

**Error:**

> [MongoError: cursor killed or timed out] name: 'MongoError', message: 'cursor killed or timed out'.

Comment: This error looks similar to this: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2667

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in my model. Needed to add dropdups:true for the unique index.